# Correct usage of YYEOF in YACC parser

Tags: parsing, flex-lexer, yacc

I've been trying to write a parser for evaluating multiple arithmetic operations in a single file. Every expression evaluates and is working fine except at the last I get this `Error` printed (`yyeerror()` is being called). So, I was trying to terminate as soon as the `EOF` character is encountered and implemented this predefined macro `YYEOF`. I still get that last redundant line printed.

lex:

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

void yyerror();
extern int yylval;

%}

%%

[ \t] ;

[0-9]+ {yylval = atoi(yytext); return INTEGER;}

[\-\+\*\/\n\(\)] return *yytext;

<<EOF>> return YYEOF;

. yyerror();

%%

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
```

yacc:

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int yylex();
void yyerror();
extern FILE* yyin;

%}

%start A
%token INTEGER
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'

%%

A : A B '\n' {printf("%d\n", $2);}
  | YYEOF {exit(0);}
  |
  ;

B : B '+' B {$$ = $1 + $3;}
  | B '-' B {$$ = $1 - $3;}
  | B '*' B {$$ = $1 * $3;}
  | B '/' B {$$ = $1 / $3;}
  | '+' B {$$ = $2;}
  | '-' B {$$ = -$2;}
  | '(' B ')' {$$ = $2;}
  | INTEGER
  ;

%%

void yyerror() {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    yyparse();
}
```

input:

[image]

output:

```
t0000@TTTT:~/practice$ ./parser input.txt
63
55
40
0
Error
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the problem wasn't in the EOF, but in the fact that your parser just didn't have a case to handle empty lines. It handles files *without* empty lines perfectly!

Putting *this* in the yacc file worked with your input (this would *print* an empty line when it *encounters* one, just as an example):

```
A : A B '\n' {printf("%d\n", $2);}
  | A '\n' {printf("\n");}
  |
  ;
```

And so, you didn't need parse EOFs explicity at all.

Comment: Thanks, I went through the yacc documentation and figured it out.